# Python SQL - What is missing that - <pyodbc.Cursor at 0x2b9b4266f30>

Tags: python, sql

```
import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={SQL Server};Server=DESKTOP-5QSCP7A;Database=AdventureWorks2012;Trusted_Connection=yes;')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM [Person].[Person] WHERE MiddleName='M' AND FirstName='Abigail'")
```

Comment: This is what I am getting as a result: <pyodbc.Cursor at 0x2b9b4266f30>

Comment: You should add explanation of your problem, not only the code.